# How can I see where my amenities come from?

Tags: civilization-6

In the image below you can see that I have two amenities, one from a luxury resource, and one from entertainment source, where can I see what entertainment is giving this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of an easy way to tell, but there are several things to check.

1. Entertainment Districts - has this city built one?
2. Zoos and Stadiums nearby - these structures have a range of 6 tiles.  Is there a zoo within 6 tiles?
3. Wonders - Colosseum extends out 6 tiles.  http://civ6.gamepedia.com/Wonder lists all wonders and their effects, including amenities.

In your situation, I would guess an Entertainment district.

Answer (score 1):

In your screenshot, there is a **View Reports** button top left. It is now a button with an icon, most likely due to a patch. It's possible that my explanation here is something that was only added in a later patch compared to your screenshot; I can't be sure. All I know is that my information is correct **today** (well, technically yesterday when I played).

There are three tabs in the reports window.

IIRC, the *middle* tab shows you a breakdown of all your resources (luxury, strategic, ...). At the bottom of every luxury resource segment, there is an arrow icon. When you hover over that arrow, it will tell you *which* cities are receiving this particular luxury resource.

On the third tab, you can see a city breakdown, including an amenities counter (e.g. **4/3**), meaning that you have 4 amenities but the population only needs 3 (excess amenities leads to citizen happiness, which is another column on the report).

*Edit:* As far as I'm aware, there's no place where you can see a list of amenities that a particular city has, you can only piece it together by looking at the resources report.